# can an iPhone application create more than one button on the applications screen?

Tags: iphone

I'd rather write an application with two buttons on the applications menu than use just one - and have two paths through the app.

Can this be done?

Is there some way of creating buttons on the applications screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The iPhone's home screen doesn't have "buttons"—it has app icons. Each icon represents an app; when the icon is tapped, the app is opened. If you wanted multiple icons, you would need multiple apps. You could potentially create another app that, when launched, closed itself and opened your main app using a URL (see [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)).

Why do you want to have multiple icons that open the same app? It sounds quite illogical to me...

Comment: The user will need to download both applications individually though. There's no way to install one application and have it automatically create another icon or install another application. The web clipping strategy isn't any better (still requires manual user action).

Answer (score 3):

I want to say this is not possible due to the bundle identifiers of the application having to be different but I am relatively new to iPhone programming so someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could come would be to use web clippings (ie, add a webpage icon to the launcher from Safari) that could then use a URL scheme to launch your app. Currently, there's no programatic way to create these icons, they must be created via safari.